# Dropbox Uploader Modification

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed, dropbox

Is anyone of you familiar with Dropbox Uploader (https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader) or UNIX `sed` command.

I would like to get this script to work so it would return an sorted list from dropbox based on modified date.

Command `./droptobox list Test` outputs:

```
Listing "/Test"... DONE
[F] config.bmp
[F] igs.bin
```

---

If to do some modifications to script (echoing out `$DIR_CONTENT`), I can see from the output that there certainly is information I need.

```
{"revision": 37, "rev": "2514cf1330", "thumb_exists": true, "bytes": 824, "modified": "Thu, 07 Nov 2013 16:14:59 +0000", "client_mtime": "Thu, 07 Nov 2013 16:14:59 +0000", "path": "/Test/config.bmp", "is_dir": false, "icon": "page_white_picture", "root": "dropbox", "mime_type": "image/x-ms-bmp", "size": "824 bytes"}

{"revision": 38, "rev": "2614cf1330", "thumb_exists": false, "bytes": 86, "modified": "Thu, 07 Nov 2013 16:15:18 +0000", "client_mtime": "Thu, 07 Nov 2013 16:15:18 +0000", "path": "/Test/igs.bin", "is_dir": false, "icon": "page_white", "root": "dropbox", "mime_type": "application/octet-stream", "size": "86 bytes"}], "size": "0 bytes"}
```

---

I suppose this is the line that responsible for it:

```
echo "$DIR_CONTENT" | sed -n 's/.*"path": *"\([^"]*\)",.*"is_dir": *\([^"]*\),.*/\1:\2/p' > $RESPONSE_FILE
```

The problem is that I ain't that familiar with `sed`, if I try to do some modifications I won't get any output.

Modified line (have no idea if I'm moving in right direction):

```
echo "$DIR_CONTENT" | sed -n 's/.*"path": *"\([^"]*\)",.*"is_dir": *\([^"]*\),.*"modified": *\([^"]*\),.*/\1:\2\3/p' > $RESPONSE_FILE
```

But ideally would it be possible to get it to display modified information and sort the results based on it?

Also other part of the `db_list` function:

```
        #For each line...
        while read -r line; do

            local FILE=${line%:*}
            FILE=${FILE##*/}
            local TYPE=${line#*:}

            if [[ $TYPE == "false" ]]; then
                echo -ne " [F] $FILE\n"
            else
                echo -ne " [D] $FILE\n"
            fi
        done < $RESPONSE_FILE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things I see:

1. The "is_dir" value is a boolean and does not have quotes, so change

   ```
   "is_dir": *\([^"]*\),
   ```

   to

   ```
   "is_dir": *\([^,]*\),
   ```
2. "modified" occurs before "path", so you need to write (accounting for quotes as well):

   ```
   echo "$DIR_CONTENT" | sed -n 's/.*"modified": *"\([^"]*\)",.*"path": *"\([^"]*\)",.*"is_dir": *\([^,]*\),.*/\2:\3 \1/p' > $RESPONSE_FILE
   ```

Also, bash has a handy "here-string" feature, so you don't need to "echo"

```
sed -n '...' <<< "$DIR_CONTENT" > "$RESPONSE_FILE"
```

Comment: Greetings, I'm very thankful for the help, kinda have better understanding now how it works and what did I do wrong, but file type check returns wrong result now. 

Probably because of: 
"local TYPE=${line#*:}" line ?

Comment: That [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) will remove from the beginning of the "$line" string up to and including the first colon. Is that what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: Pretty much yes, only the "if [[ $TYPE == "false" ]]; then" check lists all files as directories even when they are not. Haven't managed to fix it myself yet.

Comment: The only boolean fields in the sample you posted are thumb_exists and is_dir. What is TYPE supposed to represent?

Comment: TYPE is suppose to represent is_dir, but by echoing out modified date, it seems to be have problem getting the value. I also have example of type check above. I just cant figure out the how to correct "local TYPE=${line#*:}". Instead of "false" it returns "false:Mon, 04 Nov 2013 03:29:58 +0000". I just have no idea how to also get rid of everything after second colon.

Comment: You just need to take another step:  `local TYPE=${line#*:}; TYPE=${TYPE%%:*}`

Comment: I got everything working as I wanted, including the sorting part. Thank you Glenn for your help :)